# How to change the value of ui:outputText in second div onchange inputfiled in aura iteration in one div

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

I have below an aura component and a controller function,  I want to change the value of `ui:outputText` on change order Price of `lightning:input`. Now getting the current input box value in the controller.

**Aura Component:**

```html
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" 
                access="global" controller="PricingApprovalQuote">

    <aura:attribute name="InstnceOfLineItem" type="List" />  

    <aura:attribute name = "recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="LYDCNR" type="Double"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="myText" type="decimal"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.InstnceOfLineItem}" var="instance" indexVar="mduindex">
    <div class="c-container">
        <div class="slds-border_bottom" data-index="{!mduIndex}">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_8-of-12">
                    <lightning:layout >
                    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                    <div class="header-column">
                    <lightning:input name="{!index}" label="Order Price" value = "{!instance.unitprice}" onchange="{! c.orderPriceChange}"/>

                    </div>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                    <div class="header-column">
                    <lightning:input name="input1" label="Commission" value = ""/>

                    </div>
                    </lightning:layoutItem>
                    </lightning:layout> 
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_4-of-12">
                <lightning:layout >
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                <div class="header-column">
                <p class="field-title" title="DCNR% at Projected cost for(proposed/order price)" style="color: rgb(0, 112, 210);"><b>DCNR% at Projected Cost For<br/> (Proposed/Order Price) </b></p>
                <ui:outputText value="{!instance.DCNRProjectedCost}" />

                </div>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                </lightning:layout>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </aura:iteration>
    </aura:component>
```

---

**Controller:**

```js
orderPriceChange : function(component, event, helper) {

        var value = event.getSource().get('v.value');
        alert('value '+value);

}
```

Comment: Use aura id as dynamically <ui:outputText  aura:id="text-input-id-1" class="field" value="{!instance.DCNRProjectedCost}"/>

Comment: Thanks Rijwan! But I need outputText value to be change  on onChange InputText of order price. how to achieve this?

Comment: in input name you use aura:id of output text and get in controller and set the output text value with aura id

Comment: As a side note, you might reconsider using `ui:outputText`. Salesforce has announced removing support for all `ui` namespaced components in May, 2021. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by following way:

**change lightning:input from**

**To**

in component file.

**And in controller get the current row and whole array:**

orderPriceChange : function(component, event, helper) {

```
    var value = event.getSource().get('v.name');
    var filteredMdu = component.get("v.InstnceOfLineItem");

    //did some calculation and update array of object

        for (var i in filteredMdu) {

            if (filteredMdu[i].opID == opId) {

                filteredMdu[i].DCNRProjectedCost = ProjectedCost;

                break;
            }
        }
        component.set("v.InstnceOfLineItem",filteredMdu);
```

}